# Effect of !important declaration when sizing (fonts) with rem

Tags: css, font-size

**UPDATE:** Please note that I am seeing this issue only in Chrome (latest version). Everything seems to be fine in Firefox.

**[By definition](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem):**

> The rem unit is relative to the root—or the `<html>`—element. That means
>   that we can define a single font size on the `<html>` element and define
>   all rem units to be a percentage of that.

Let me explain my situation with an example...

**Relevant CSS:**

```
html {
    font-size: 87.5%;
}

body {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-size: 1.21428571rem;
}

code {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
}
```

I am using the `!important` declaration to override the font-size of inline code.

The thing is, I noticed that the font-size of code blocks is much smaller than 14px, most probably 12px. But if I remove the `!important` declaration and set the font-size on a specific `code` element (styling a specific inline code element), the fonts-size is nice and fine at what appears to be 14px.

Does you have any idea as to how `!important` declarations may affect sizing in `rem`'s? (Especially considering in my case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the issue was with **(1)** `font-family` not defined for `code` and `pre` blocks, which meant Chrome and other webkit browsers chose some monospace font that appears smaller **(2)** `line-height` was smaller (almost equal to the `font-size`).

Fixing these two has solved the problem.

I have no idea why Chrome Dev Tools Web Inspector's "Computed Style" shows 11px as the font-size (also applies to any webkit browser, including Safari). I can confirm that it's showing the wrong value because by changing the font to Arial I could easily tell that it's 14px.

Also, after setting the `font-family` on `code` and `pre` blocks, Chrome now shows the correct computed `font-size` value.

Answer (score 2):

First off `!important` is lazy coding and dangerous to maintainability. It's toxic and breaks the nature of CSS (the Cascading portion). Avoid it at all costs.

Second:

```
code {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
}
```

Might as well be written:

```
code {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
}
```

The second rule overrides the first (again, the Cascading nature of CSS)

`rem` stands for root em, which is the font-size of the top level element (i.e., html)

and what your rule is saying 1 x the em of the html element, with is 87.5% of the browser default.

**EDIT:**

Your `<p>` tags have a `font-size` of 100% inherited from the parent element which is eventually inherited from `body` and `body` has a `1.2142857rem` which is roughly 17px This is why you're seeing a difference in font sizes, which is also exacerbated by the the difference of monospace and sans serif fonts.

Comment: **(1)** I have to use `!important` because I am overriding the style of `.entry-content code` in default stylesheet with `code` in my child theme's (WordPress) stylesheet. I don't want to touch the parent stylesheet. If I modify `.entry-content code` I'd have to modify numerous others.

Comment: **(2)** `font-size: 14px !important;` is for older browsers. Even IE8 doesn't support `rem` I am told.

Comment: You don't *have* to use `!important` if you refactored your css to have better specificity you wouldn't need it. Also check my edit for a detailed description of what's going on.

Comment: The point I don't understand is, why does `1.2142857rem`, that is the font-size set on `body`, `p` or any other element, matter? The font-size of `code` (1rem) should be governed by that of `html` (87.5%). 1rem should always be equal to 14px (as long as the browser's default is 16px)... am I wrong? (also, I can confirm that the issue persists in the latest version of Chrome — everything's fine in Firefox)

Comment: hmm... no. The issue persists in Firefox as well, it's just not as visible as in Chrome.

Comment: I can confirm with Firebug that the computed value is 14px as expected on Firefox 14.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep. You are right. Everything's fine in Firefox. The slight difference I saw was due to the line-height difference in the two pages. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm seeing it now, I thought you were talking about the inline `code` tag. This has to be a bug in Chrome, it seems to be using the `body` as the root em when inside the `pre` tag. If you remove the code the rem on the pre tag is correct.

Comment: However, if I set the `pre` tag to use 1rem it seems to fix the issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/E9Eu9/ http://jsfiddle.net/E9Eu9/1/

Comment: Thanks for your time, after working on it for hours, I finally realized what was causing the problem. Please see my answer below.